# Variable from JSON content as value for a counter

Tags: swiftui

I'm literally starting programming, so sorry for the rookie question.
I'm working in Xcode/SwiftUI and trying to make a counter where the inial value comes from a JSON file.

I manage to extract the value for strings... but after spending hours trying to find out how to set the initial counter to the value "hull", I'm finally asking help!

My JSON file is formatted as such:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Chaser",
        "type": "Level 1",
        "hull": 5,
        "shields": 0,
        "imageName": "chaser"
    },
```

and my struct is like this:

```
struct Enemy: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var type: String
    var hull: Int
    var shields: Int
    fileprivate var imageName: String

}
```

In my page, my code is like this:

```
struct EnemyDetails: View {

    @State var count : Int = 0

    var enemy : Enemy

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            EnemyImage(image: Image("EnemyImage"))
                .frame(height:300)

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(enemy.name).font(.title)
                Text(enemy.type)
                Spacer()

                HStack {
                    Button(action: {self.count = self.count - 1}) {
                    Image("Decrease")
                    }.padding(20)
                    Text("\(count)").font(.system(size:100)).padding(20)
                    Button(action: {self.count = self.count + 1}) {
                    Image("Increase")
                    }.padding(20)
                }
                Spacer()

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I would like the value "Count" to be the value "Hull" from the JSON file.

Can anyone help?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
struct EnemyDetails: View {

    var enemy : Enemy
    @State private var count : Int // don't initialise here

    init(enemy: Enemy) {
       self.enemy = enemy
       _count = State(initialValue: enemy.hull)  // << initial state !!
    }

    // ... other your code
```